# Reading R-Errors through JRI

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

i'm using JRI, to talk to R through Java. If i try to get the result of my R-Code as Double i get a NullPointer. Normally this is caused by an error of R. Is it possible to get the output of the R-Console into Java in order to read the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Here is what I did, to solve the problem.

because my REngine is a singleton i was able to perform those R-Expressions, after the creation:

```
re.eval("log<-file('"+filepath+"')");
re.eval("sink(log, append=TRUE)");
re.eval("sink(log, append=TRUE, type='message')");
```

this codes writes every R-Output into the file specified by the String filepath. For non-singletons i would recommend to extend the REngine...

Comment: This is a peaty cool solution, although i wonder if there is a possibility to send the r console output into the java output.