# Sending R-Errors (from the console) into the Java standard output, when using JRI

Tags: java, r, jri

Inside my Java code I'm using the `eval` method (`JRI`) to run R commands within Java (I'm not interested in reading .R files through `source` command , due to distribution considerations).

I'm trying to debug my R code within Java.

Although i ran into an interesting solution in [Reading R-Errors through JRI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916142/reading-r-errors-through-jri) , which uses the `sink` function in R, I'm looking for a way to import the R console output straight into my Java output (it seems more comfortable).

Has anyone of you ever managed to import R console output straight into the Java output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User @Daniel https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107657/daniel

Gave a great answer to this in :

[Get same output as R console in Java using JRI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315947/get-same-output-as-r-console-in-java-using-jri)